# sequencing the match week

Tags: python, pandas, sequence, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file that contains football results since 2005.
You can find the data file below link.
[Click here to download the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1noRBphUam60mpxHB9iZAz2zj7pN8XPsF)

The shape of df is (23758,24)
I would like to create a new column that sequence all the match based on the column **Div**

Div contains 5 groups such as **E0**,**F1**, **I1**,**SP1**,**D1**.

E0,F1,I1,SP1 contains 380 matches in a year (i.e.date ranges from Aug 2005/ May 2006) whereas D1 contains 306 matches.

The sequencing that I want to do is to number every 10 matches for E0,F1,I1,SP1  and every 9 matches for D1.

That means that the first 10 matches for E0,F1,I1,SP1 will be 1 and the following 10 matches will be 2 etc. Similarly the first 9 matches for D1 will be assigned as 1, the following 9 matches will be assigned as 2 etc.

The number will be restarted if it reaches to 39 for E0,F1,I1,SP1. That means if it hits 39, then it will be assigned as 1 again.

The number will be restarted if it reaches to 35 for D1, it means D1 will only have 1 to 34, E0,F1,I1,SP1  will only have 1 to 38.

```
df ['GW'] = ((data.groupby('Div').cumcount())/10).astype('int64')+1
```

I tried above but it sequence all the way. And I need to cut off at 38 for  **E0,F1,I1,SP1** and 34 for **D1**
I have created a sample dataframe similar to my data uploaded above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['HomeTeam'] = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
df['Div'] = ['E1','E1','E2','E2','E3','E3','E4','E4','E5','E5','E1','E1','E2','E2','E3','E4','E4','E4','E5','E5','E1','E1','E2','E2','E3','E4','E4','E4','E5','E5','E1','E1','E2','E2','E3','E4','E4','E4','E5','E5']
```

The expected output is as follow:

```
df['GW'] = ['1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2',
            '1','2']
```

Above simple data frame

Can anyone one advise how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us you sample data , try to summaries your data , look into the whole data set is way too much for us

Comment: Hi Wen,
thanks for the reply.
I added sample dataframe

Comment: Base on the above data what is you expected output ?

Comment: I added expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this ? np.arange(len(df))%2+1

Comment: I tried this.
df ['GW'] = ((data.groupby('Div').cumcount())/10).astype('int64')+1
But i have to cut off at 38 for for E0,F1,I1,SP1  and 34 for D1, How would I do that?